# Google Cloud BigTable Connection Issues

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to create a simple connection to BigTable, however I think my dependencies are incorrect. As I understand it, if I have a standalone java application, the only thing I need to import is the bigtable-hbase-1.x as seen below, however, that appears to not include some needed hbase classes.  Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_x.BigtableConnection
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:99)
    at com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld.HelloWorld.connect(HelloWorld.java:14)
    at com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:19)
```

CODE

```
package com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld;

import com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloWorld {
    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "______";
    private static final String INSTANCE_ID = "_______";

    //private static Connection connection = null;

    public static void connect() throws IOException {
        BigtableConfiguration.connect(PROJECT_ID, INSTANCE_ID);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ~ Copyright (c) 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. ~ ~ Licensed under 
    the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you ~ may not use this file 
    except in compliance with the License. You may ~ obtain a copy of the License 
    at ~ ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 ~ ~ Unless required by 
    applicable law or agreed to in writing, software ~ distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or ~ implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing ~ permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.bigtable.helloworld</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloud-bigtable-hello-world</artifactId>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cloud-bigtable-hello-world</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <bigtable.version>1.0.0-pre1</bigtable.version>
        <hbase.version>1.1.5</hbase.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots-repo</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- <repository> <releases> <enabled>true</enabled> <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy> 
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy> </releases> <snapshots> <enabled>false</enabled> 
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy> <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy> 
            </snapshots> <id>google-maven-central</id> <name>Google Maven Central</name> 
            <url>https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com</url> <layout>default</layout> 
            </repository> -->
    </repositories>

    <!-- <pluginRepositories> <pluginRepository> <releases> <enabled>true</enabled> 
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy> <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy> 
        </releases> <snapshots> <enabled>false</enabled> <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy> 
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy> </snapshots> <id>google-maven-central</id> 
        <name>Google Maven Central</name> <url>https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com</url> 
        <layout>default</layout> </pluginRepository> </pluginRepositories> -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
            <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.x</artifactId>
            <version>${bigtable.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.33.Fork26</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.90.3</version>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How are you executing this code?  Have you tried this: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld.HelloWorld"`?  I didn't get that  exception with that pom.xml and java file when I ran that way.

Comment: I believe I had a corrupted dependency jar. I started clean and am running 1.0.0-pre3, and all is good. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @PaulMazzuca — great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please copy your comment into an answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had a corrupted dependency jar. I started clean and am running 1.0.0-pre3, and all is good. Thanks for the response